# Error occurs while installing eclipse EE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am beginner in java programming.Last one year I am using Netbeans IDE to run java program.It works perfectly.Yesterday I downloaded **Eclipse EE OXYGEN VERSION**. I tried to install but it shows an error like **JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE LAUNCHER ERROR**.can anyone solve this issue?Thanks in advance...

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will try to create Java virtual machine with the memory settings you mention in eclipse.ini file.

Go ahead and check for lines that looks like -Xmx1024m or -Xmx512m and try to reduce it to a lesse value and see if this solves the issue. This is the memory being allocated and some systems are better suited to allocating less memory.

Comment: bro where I have to reduce the memory?

Comment: YES I HAVE THIS  statement  "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"

Comment: what I should do?

Comment: @vigneshvictory check if you have java version 1.8 installed in your machine. Next modify the Xmx1024m to Xmx512m and try

Comment: Thank you for your concern I installed mars version it works perfectly....

Comment: If the answer helped, be sure to select it as the correct answer!